# Regex, searching for multiple newlines

Tags: javascript, regex, text

I have a regex which searches for a newline symbol:

```
\r?\n|\r
```

And two examples:

```
#Example-1#
The correct answer is (B) 2 to 3. jfbgfdgdf sgdsgsd.

jfbgfdgdf sgdsgsd.
#End Example-1#

#Example-2#
The correct answer is (B) 2 to 3. jfbgfdgdf sgdsgsd.
jfbgfdgdf sgdsgsd.
#End Example-2#
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zQ3nR3/1

I need to update a regex, so it finds only multiple instances of newline symbol, like these in Example-1 between text lines and not the one between text lines in Example-2

Comment: Like [`(\r?\n|\r){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/zQ3nR3/2)?

Comment: you could use curly brackets like this `\\s{2,}`. This does only find two or more instances of a whitespace

Answer (score 3):

To match just the multiple linebreaks inside `#Example` text, use a limiting quantifier `{2,}` applied to `(?:\r?\n|\r)` and restrict it with a look-ahead:

```
(\r?\n|\r){2,}(?!#Example-\d)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR2bH5/1)

The `(?!#Example-\d)` look-ahead returns a match only if there is no `#Example-`+`digit` after the multiple newline symbols.

Answer (score 2):

```
(\r?\n|\r)\d*(\r?\n|\r)
```

should do the trick, see https://regex101.com/r/zQ3nR3/3

It searches for a newline in the way you did, followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by another empty line.

---

```
((\r?\n|\r)\d*)+(\r?\n|\r)
```

would search for multiple empty lines (they could contain any whitespace, though), see https://regex101.com/r/zQ3nR3/4